# SQL Server Failed Login Attempts "Microl Office"

Tags: login, sql-server

SQL Server has a long history of failed login attempts into the SA user , occuring about 50 times every 10-20 minutes. and Extended Event auditing shows that the client_app_name is "Microl office":

[image]

The PID refers to sqlserver.exe.

- Incoming remote connections is disabled for this server so it can't be coming from outside the machine...
- No firewall rule exist for SQL server so incoming connections are blocked there too
- No jobs are attempting to login

Any ideas what else this could be or suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a user `sa`?

Comment: There is a [lot of malware with the company or product name "Microl Office"](http://www.isthisfilesafe.com/company/Microl%20office_details.aspx)

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes I have a user "sa"... It would seem sqlserver is additionally on that list then since the malware has affected it.

Comment: More likely is you have malware and it is **targeting** SQLServer.